Camel Kafka - consumersCount and groupInstanceId
When configuring Apache Camel as a consumer for Apache Kafka, you can set many configuration options including the following that are relevant for this question:
groupInstanceId. consumersCount, and potentially groupId.
The consumersCount parameter allows multiple instances of the Kafka consumer to run from a single deployment. The Camel code will start multiple Kafka consumers in parallel.
The groupInstanceId parameter changes the way Kafka interacts with the consumer, from being a dynamic consumer to a static consumer; which ensures that the same group instance is always assigned to the same partitions.


Now, I have some questions about this (what happens if one group instance is started initially, which would read all partitions; then a second is added. Would the second then take over half of the partitions, meaning the group instance is not really statically assigned always to the same set of partitions?) - but my main question is this:
What will Camel do when both parameters are provided? Will each instance be given some unique group instance ID based on the provided ID and the consumer count (e.g. groupInstanceID1, groupInstanceID2, etc.)? Or will Camel start multiple consumers with the same groupInstanceID, and so fail?
I provide a group ID (which will clearly be the same for all instances, as the individual instances are managed by Camel) if that makes a difference

Did you try it? What did you experience vs what you expected? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Unique consumer groups (group.id configs) are completely independent of one another

The group ID will be the same for all consumers, so this doesn't answer the question I don't think

@simon Your question really has nothing to do with Camel - these properties are passed into the raw KafkaConsumer config. Starting any consumer with the group.id will consume all partitions yes. Start another instance with different id - also consuming all partitions... Start a consumer with a matching group, the consumer group "rebalances" and dustributes the partitions based on the Assignor logic... It is not guaranteed to be evenly distributed

Thanks, that makes sense as an answer to my side-question. I think my main question, about how Camel assigns identifiers to multiple instances of a consumer in a group, is relevant though. You can give a group.instance.id and define the consumersCount and I'm asking how those two work together

Well, what is happening vs what you expect? consumersCount could start new threads or sub-processes. It doesn't change the answer... spring-kafka also has a setting called parllelism, which may be the same as consumerCount. Also see https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer
